# how add custom column to grid view without affecting the database?

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I need to add new column in to grid view that not included in the database. and I don't need to send data that insert to that column to the database.
how i need to do that in yii2 php framework explain it step by step.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: i need to add new column to grid viwe that created using crud generater  include checkboxes. selected value not needed to store in database

Comment: So you want separate column with checkboxes for selecting rows?

Comment: yes within the  grid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in column for this purpose. It's called [CheckboxColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html) and can be added to all columns like that:

```
'columns' => [
    // ...
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        // you may configure additional properties here
    ],
],
```

To get selected rows use the following javascript code:

```
var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
// keys is an array consisting of the keys associated with the selected rows
```